# How can I play a css animation in b.html when a button is clicked in a.html and still use the same javascript file?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, addeventlistener, window.location

Im making a website where users can personalize their pizza. If the button `deliverPizzaButton` is clicked I want to redirect the user to another html page where an animation will be played which will let them know the pizza is on their way.

This is what I have now in my javascript, it is redirecting to the second HTML but the animation does not play in the second html

```
var pizzaDelivererImg = document.getElementById('pizzaDeliverer');


function changeHTML() {
    if (deliverPizzaButton.classList == ('readyToDeliver')) { // when all the steps are completed the button will change color and the button can be clicked
        window.location.href = 'pizzaAnimation.html';
        playAnimation();
    }
}

deliverPizzaButton.addEventListener('click', changeHTML);

function playAnimation() {
    if (window.location.href == 'pizzaAnimation.html') {
        pizzaDelivererImg.classList.add('letTheDelivererDrive');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.letTheDelivererDrive {
    animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*when the spec is finished*/
    -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
    -moz-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 4s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*FF 5+*/
    -o-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 4s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*Not implemented yet*/
    -ms-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 4s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*IE 10+*/
}

@keyframes animationFrames {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-355px, -31px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(309px, -26px);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animationFrames {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate(-355px, -31px);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate(309px, -26px);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-355px, -31px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(309px, -26px);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes animationFrames {
    0% {
        -o-transform: translate(-355px, -31px);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translate(309px, -26px);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes animationFrames {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translate(-355px, -31px);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translate(309px, -26px);
    }
}
```

HTML 1 (index.html) (where the button will be clicked to redirect):

```
<img id="pizzaDeliverer" src="img/pizzadeliverer.png" alt="pizza deliverer">
```

HTML 2 (pizzaAnimation.html) (where the animation will be played):

it is linked to the same css and script as in index.html

```
<img id="pizzaDeliverer" src="img/pizzadeliverer.png" alt="pizza deliverer">
```

Comment: You are redirecting to another page and playing the animation on other page, do it on the same page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to run code after the browser has been told to unload the current page and head to another one.

```
    window.location.href = 'pizzaAnimation.html';
    playAnimation(); //<-- this won't happen because of ^^
```

So in effect you're telling it to play the animation on the first page, not the second one. What you need to do instead is modify the JS to act **onload** for the second page, and then run the animation.

```
function playAnimation() {
    pizzaDelivererImg.classList.add('letTheDelivererDrive');
}
if (window.location.href == 'pizzaAnimation.html') playAnimation();
```

Also note that

```
deliverPizzaButton.classList == ('readyToDeliver')
```

...is not a proper, scalable implementation of `classList`. Better would be:

```
deliverPizzaButton.classList.contains('readyToDeliver')
```